# Sony VAIO keyboard only responding after suspending the device/restarting the X-Server

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, laptop, vaio, sony

As the title says, the built in keyboard on my Sony VAIO SVE1712V1EB does not respond after booting. Neither it does in GRUB.

However when I suspend the computer / restart the X-Server, the keyboard is recognized and works fine.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have set the bootmode of UEFI to legacy.

What do I have to do to get the Keyboard working immediately after booting?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it was solved with installation of new drivers for touchpad. 
Download this [archive](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz) (from Ubuntu's bug reporting page).
Open a terminal, and follow these steps (after step 4, you will have no mouse at all):

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c 
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Solution details can be found here - http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/